# Is there a method or way to mask one ui image from multiple images?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

Currently, i am working on a game project as a hobby and have been trying to make some game mechanics that i havent really made before. I am currently working on an inventory system for the player that displays the player's weapon collection as well as weapon parts.

[image: Showcase of the two inventory systems]

I am currently working on making the weapon inventory. My current problem is rendering the weapon models as icons per inventory slot.

The current method that I am planning on rendering any 3D asset is by using a camera with a render texture and assigning that texture to a RawImage Component. I was planning to do the same for the inventory slots. However, I realised that i would need a camera per slot with its own render texture which would be both time consuming to create as well as making the game less performant (since there would be a lot of cameras).

I have searched if there is a way to mask a texture from multiple objects so that I can skip the part of creating 100 different cameras and instead use one. So far, nothing has come up in my findings that could remotely help me.

So, as stated in the title; Is there a method or way to mask one ui image from multiple images? If not, is there an alternative solution to my problem?

Comment: Why do you need a mask in first instance ?

Comment: I want to use only a small part of the render texture that the camera is generating. Masking has helped me a lot in that department as i can use the UI elements that i have created for anything i want.

Comment: Maybe instead of using RenderTexture you will try set models to UI? With using Unity UI Camera Space. This may help you, without using a lot of cameras. Or you can use sprites instead of models, this much performant.

Comment: I dont really know much about Unity UI Camera Space but i will check it out and see what i can do. I am trying to avoid using sprites since I want to show the player what he/she has created from the crafting menu via icons both in-game and in the crafting terminal menu.